# Cannot install GDAL on docker container

Tags: docker, gdal

I need to install the latest version of gdal on another docker image. I cant run the osgeo/gdal container separately, because i need the python bindings.

When i run the next code in docker

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.3-python3.9
USER root

RUN apt install update
RUN apt-get install -y \
         build-essential \
         python-all-dev \
         python-is-python3 \
         libproj-dev \
         libpq-dev \
         libgeos-dev \
         wget


RUN wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.4.0/gdal-3.4.0.tar.gz
RUN tar xvfz gdal-3.4.0.tar.gz
WORKDIR ./gdal-3.4.0
RUN ./configure --with-python --with-pg --with-geos
RUN make
RUN make install
RUN ldconfig
```

I get the next error:

```
configure: error: PROJ 6 symbols not found
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -o errexit -o nounset -o nolog -c ./configure --with-python --with-pg --with-geos' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Debian already has a [packaged version of GDAL 3.2.2](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libgdal28); is this new enough for you?  If not, can you edit the question to include a more complete error?

Comment: No, i need the newest version, otherwise the software that use gdal won't work.

Comment: When i do ```apt list installed libproj-dev```, i get this ```libproj-dev/now 5.2.0-1 amd64 [installed,local]```. this is not version 6

Comment: So is it possible to upgrade debian 10 to 11 in the dockerfile, to get a newer version of libproj-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already noticed, the version available via `apt(-get)` is `<6` which explains the error. One way around it is to compile `PROJ` from source. For instance:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.3-python3.9

USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    python-all-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libgeos-dev \
    wget \
    curl \
    sqlite3 \
    cmake \
    libtiff-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    pkg-config


# This is just an example with hard-coded paths/uris and no cleanup...
RUN curl https://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-8.2.1.tar.gz | tar -xz &&\
    cd proj-8.2.1 &&\
    mkdir build &&\
    cd build && \
    cmake .. &&\
    make && \
    make install

RUN wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.4.0/gdal-3.4.0.tar.gz
RUN tar xvfz gdal-3.4.0.tar.gz
WORKDIR ./gdal-3.4.0
RUN ./configure --with-python --with-pg --with-geos &&\
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I can clean this up by delete the proj and gdal folder, right.

Comment: Yeah, clean the source code up as well as build dependencies. Remember that images are layered, so you may want to not install all dependencies at the beginning, but install build dependencies, build the lib, and remove the dependencies and src and build folder all in one `RUN` command to minimize the size of the created layer. You can also clear the apt cache to save space.

Comment: only that is not possible in a Dockerfile, ```cd ./dirname``` doen't work in a Dockerfile. you need the command ```WORKDIR ./dirname``` to change the directory.

Comment: It does work, but it will only change the directory temporarily during that `RUN` step (i.e., at build-time)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.6.3
USER root
RUN apt update && apt install -y gdal-bin libgdal-dev g++

USER airflow
RUN pip install pygdal==$(gdal-config --version).*
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}"
```